Синонимизировать метки [pil] и [pillow]
Предлагаю объединить/синонимизировать метки pil и pillow

pil - 123 вопроса
pillow - 197 вопросов

Для контекста: PIL - Python Imaging Library, разработка исходного проекта была прекращена, была продолжена в форке под названием Pillow, при этом имя импортируемого модуля осталось PIL.
Как основную метку предлагаю использовать pillow, субъективно мне кажется, что по этому наименованию лучше ищется, плюс это актуальное название библиотеки.

Так может надо для старой версии оставить старую метку? // cc @αλεχολυτ

@Qwertiy не делать синонимы, не объединять? Или что ты под этим подразумеваешь?

@αλεχολυτ, ага.

@Qwertiy старая версия библиотеки не используется как таковая уже давно. В любом случае нужно оставить одну метку, т.к. фактически это одна и та же библиотека.

@insolor, но ведь по ней есть старые вопросы, касающиеся именно её.

@Qwertiy на enSO всё слито и я не вижу в этом проблемы. Ты ожидаешь, что кто-то не сможет найти решение для старой заброщенной версии?

@Qwertiy теоретически да, но практически - последняя версия pil выпущена в 2006 году, первая версия pillow - в 2010. По незнанию кто-то мог использовать pil, но по идее они должны быть между собой совместимы (точно не знаю). Я считаю, что тут не нужно сильно заморачиваться, а просто считать, что это одна и та же библиотека с двумя разными названиями (исторически).


одна и та же библиотека, и актуальное название сейчас - pillow


Готово!
updating post history, 138 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 123 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 77 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'pil': [pil] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 274
tag remapping of [pillow] and [pil] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
30 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym pil -> pillow was approved!

